# Elasticsearch: too many shards

Tags: python, elasticsearch, lucene, sharding

I try to access 10 of the most common term in my index by doing:

```
POST _search/
{  
  "size":0,
  "aggs":{  
     "top-terms-aggregation":{  
        "terms":{  
           "field":"author_wording",
           "size":10
        }
     }
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
{
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Trying to query 1157 shards, which is over the limit of 1000. This limit exists because querying many shards at the same time can make the job of the coordinating node very CPU and/or memory intensive. It is usually a better idea to have a smaller number of larger shards. Update [action.search.shard_count.limit] to a greater value if you really want to query that many shards at the same time."
  }
```

The problem is that I didn't configure that many shard. In my index I've got only one shard defined in my settings:

```
"index" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 1,
    "number_of_replicas" : 0
 }
```

Where this error is coming from? How can I reduce my number of shards?

Comment: Just add the index name before `_search` like `/my_index/_search` otherwise you're searching over all indices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you curios about what are does shards you can use the cat api:

```
GET /_cat/shards
```

Comment: All except 2 are unassigned how can I terminate them?

Comment: You cannot delete shards, just indices.
You can delete the entire index by:
DELETE /indexName